# Getting data from Census Data API is not working

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, census

I am trying to get data form Census Track data in Anaconda and jupyter-nootbook using Pandas, but I am keep getting error.
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import geopandas as gpd

year = '2021'
variable = 'B09019_003E'
with open (r"pathToKeyFile/census_api.txt", "r") as f:
    c = f.read();

url='https://api.census.gov/data/{0}/acs/acs5?get=NAME,{1}&for=tract:*&in=state:12%20county:057&key={2}'\
    .format(year, variable, c)
response = requests.request("GET",url)

response.raise_for_status()

print(response.json)

temp = pd.DataFrame(response.json()[1:], columns=response.json()[0])
```

'print(response.json)' output:

```css
b'\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <title>Invalid Key</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <p>\n            A valid <em>key</em> must be included with each data API request.\n            You included a key with this request, however, it is not valid.\n            Please check your key and try again.\n        </p>\n        <p>\n            If you do not have a key you may sign up for one <a href="key_signup.html">here</a>.\n        </p>\n    </body>\n</html>\n'
```

My census_api.txt only contains the key. This is the error when running pd.DataFrame()

```
SONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:971, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    970 try:
--> 971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    972 except JSONDecodeError as e:
    973     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    974     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    333 """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334 containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336 """
--> 337 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338 end = _w(s, end).end()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 temp = pd.DataFrame(response.json()[1:], columns=response.json()[0])
      2 temp['state'] = temp['state'].astype('str')
      3 temp['county'] = temp['county'].astype('str')

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:975, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    971     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    972 except JSONDecodeError as e:
    973     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    974     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError
--> 975     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

When I open the URL itself it is saying that my API key is invalid, while I am sure it is fine and I have just got that. Any thought on this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just received your API key, and activated it, then you have to wait longer for it to actually activate. I checked back within a day and my code began working.

The api will return a 200 OK and give that exact message. Give it some time. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with the census API per se. The error posted comes from the fact that the response is not valid JSON. This is not a problem for the API unless it advertises that it returns JSON in all cases.

Notice that `requests.Response#json` requires that the response text is valid  JSON. You can use `requests.Response#text` if the response is text or even `requests.Response#content` for bytes.

After making your request, call `response.raise_for_status()` in order to raise any errors (403, 404, etc.).

Once you know that the response is OK, try printing the response to see its form. It may not be a JSON. It may be rectangular, etc.

```py
import requests

year = '2021'
variable = 'B09019_003E'
with open (r"pathToKeyFile/census_api.txt", "r") as f:
    c = f.read();

url='https://api.census.gov/data/{0}/acs/acs5?get=NAME,{1}&for=tract:*&in=state:12%20county:057&key={2}'\
    .format(year, variable, c)
response = requests.request("GET",url)

response.raise_for_status() # Check for any errors

print(response.content) # Preview the output (or just save it so you can refer to it later)
```

If you'd like to update your question with the response content, we can look into getting it into a frame.

## Edit: Update to reflect new info

The response you provided indicates that your key is invalid. Here is the rendered HTML for the response:

[image]

I'm not seeing anything in the census documentation to indicate that error messages will be valid JSON (even if the response for a 200 is valid JSON).

Comment: Based on Census Documents, API returns JSON. I have updated the question add the response.content output.

Comment: @MehdiMonemi I have updated this answer to reflect the new info you provided.